# What is the best way to do not track android mixpanel events when debuggin or in debug release?

Tags: android, coding-style, solid-principles, mixpanel

My app is tracking info with mixpanel but tracks everything. So when I am testing or debugging, it tracks too. I want to know if there is a clean/best way to disable the tracking better than this in every mixpanel call:

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // track events
}
```

Comment: I would make static wrapper method(s) for MixPanel tracking methods which do make decision whether to track the event similarly as your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

They way I handled this was by creating a different project for my local/dev instances. This way I can track events without messing up with the production data.

I'm using php sdk, but you can do something similar:

```
public function loadMixPanel() {
    $token = "PRODUCTION TOKEN";
    if ($this->instance !== 'PRODUCTION') {
        $token = "TEST TOKEN";
    }
    $this->mixpanel = Mixpanel::getInstance($token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have created a final String on the class that sends the properties to Mixpanel like this:

```
private static final String MIXPANEL_PROP_BUILD_TYPE = (BuildConfig.DEBUG) ? "DEBUG_MODE" : "RELEASE_MODE";
```

And I always send this property attached to the JSON to MIXPANEL:

```
props.put(MIXPANEL_PROP_BUILD, MIXPANEL_PROP_BUILD_TYPE);
```

In mixpanel I can filter by this property.

Answer (score 0):

I am using mixpanel for tracking events in android app. For tracking events in debug and release app separately, I have created different buildtypes for debug and release version of our app by which I can give different android package names to debug and release app. In mixpanel, I have two projects for these two applications. Also, since it only changes the android package and not java package, code remains the same. You just need to select build variant (debug or release). One other advantage is that you can have both the apps simultaneously on your phone since both have different package names. Here is example gradle configuration for same.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Debug"

        buildConfigField "String", "MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN", '"asdaskjdaksdjksdhkashd"'
    }
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Release"

        buildConfigField "String", "MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN", '"asfksfkabfabsmabsmbasd"'
    }
}
```

You can get the mixpanel token with `BuildConfig.MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN` to initialize mixpanel inside activity

Answer (score 0):

BuildConfig.DEBUG doesn't work well for me and I wan't change buildTypes so I use something like the method below. This is possible because I use proguard when release an apk.

Hope this helps.

```
private static Boolean DEBUG = null;
public static boolean isDebug()
{
    // yes, it's insane but...
    if (DEBUG == null) DEBUG = MyBeautifulClassName.class.getSimpleName().contains("MyBeautifulClassName");
    return DEBUG;
}
```